Why does .NET Wasi.Sdk throw on garbage collection?
When using the .NET WASI SDK it seems the garbage collector throws, either when it runs itself in the background or when called explicitly.
I lodged an issue on Github but Microsoft are not responding (there's another similar issue on there for over a year).
My question here is, is there some setup issue on my part? All I've done is install latest wasmtime, created a .NET 8 console application, added the latest dotnet-wasi-sdk nuget package and try to run the below program and error happens.
Funnily enough, it's able to run other far more complex code but crashes when it does it's own garbage collection.
I suspect there is a setup/configuration issue on my part. Any ideas?
Error
[wasm_trace_logger] * Assertion at /home/runner/work/dotnet-wasi-sdk/dotnet-wasi-sdk/modules/runtime/src/mono/mono/metadata/sgen-stw.c:77, condition `info->client_info.stack_start >= info->client_info.info.stack_start_limit && info->client_info.stack_start < info->client_info.info.stack_end' not met

Repo
https://github.com/HermanSchoenfeld/WasiSdkBug
Offending Code
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
}

Environment
.NET 8, .NET 7
Wasi.Sdk 0.1.4-preview.10020 and 0.1.1
wasmtime-cli 19.0.2 (040ec9209 2024-04-11)


Does it only crash when you run GC.Collect, or also during normal running?

Its "experimental" with almost now changes/commits and none in the last half year. I would consider it dead or at least not made for Net 8. First thing i would advice is going back in Net versions until it starts working.

@canton7 Both. It manages to execute fairly complex code perfectly but then I spent ages trying to figure out why it was crashing intermittently. Turns out when GC was invoked implicitly it was crashing. Same error when explicit.

@Ralf I was thinking the same yet according to lots of articles and their own marketing materials, they're pushing it as a feature of .NET 8. Also tried degrading nuget and .NET versions, same.

Unless the “experimental” word is gone and it is listed under the actual .NET release notes, it’s not considered “a feature” of whatever. WASI is a useful platform to explore, but not something you should invest right now.

Added a repo to show issue. Some targets problem I believe. https://github.com/HermanSchoenfeld/WasiSdkBug

Issue was resolved by using the WASI SDK integration in .NET 8 and not that repo.
It's all experimental but looks promising.
